# Is there a way, to "emit" a built in event, by hard coding it in Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, carousel, accordion, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I would like to link two components with each other in my Vue project.
I use two-way binding for that, so I have a parent, and two child components.

The concept:

We see a carousel in the left side of the screen, and we see an accordion in the right side. I built the carousel and the accordions with v-for from a database file.

When I click in some of the accordion it drops down, and I need a reaction from a carousel component, to slide exactly there, where I clicked in the accordion.

Like:

carousel: banana, apple, house

accordion: banana, apple house

So when im clicking in the apple accordion button, I need the slider to go to the  where are the apple is displayed, and reverse.

As I said, I already bind the two components to each other, so when I'm clicking one of the accordion buttons like @click="onShowStart(index)", I get that index in the another child too, and it's changing dynamically vica-versa by sliding or clicking. So the indexes are already linked and its dynamic.

My problem is I don't know how to trigger an event, like @sliding-start from vue instance in the watch field. So I watch the "actualPosition" prop in my component, and when its changed (from 3 to 1 for example), I would like to start a sliding event to the new value of the actualPosition.

So i need something like:

```
 this.$emit('sliding-start', actualPosition);
```

I've been sitting at this problem for days, but I think my whole thinking is wrong. But before i believe this, im asking you first.

### Here is my code for the Parent component:

```
        <div class="row">
            <carousel :actualPosition="actualPosition" class="col bg-dark" @sendTheCarouselPosition="updateAccordion($event)"></carousel>
            <accordion :actualPosition="actualPosition" class="col bg-dark" @sendTheAccordionlPosition="updateCarousel($event)"></accordion>
        </div>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                actualPosition: null,
            }
        },

        methods:{
            updateAccordion: function (updatedAccordion){
                this.actualPosition = updatedAccordion;
            },
            updateCarousel: function(updatedSlider){
                this.actualPosition = updatedSlider
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

### My Accordion component:

```
<template>
    <div role="tablist">
        <b-card no-body class="mb-1" v-for="(item, index) in dataForProject">
            <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
                <b-button block href="#" v-b-toggle="'accordion-' + index" variant="info" @click="onShowStart(index)" >{{ item.title }}</b-button>
            </b-card-header>
            <b-collapse :id="'accordion-' + index" visible accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
                <b-card-body>

                    <div>
                        <h1>data from Carousel sibling: {{ actualPosition }}</h1>
                    </div>

                    <b-card-text>{{ item.content }}</b-card-text>
                </b-card-body>
            </b-collapse>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import myDataBase from '../data2'

    export default {

        props:['actualPosition'],

        watch:{
            actualPosition: function () {


            },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                dataForProject: myDataBase,
            }
        },

        methods:{
            onShowStart: function (accordionIndex) {
                this.$emit('sendTheAccordionlPosition', accordionIndex);

            },



        },
    }
</script>
```

### And my Carousel component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="mt-4 text-white">
            data from Accordion sibling: {{ actualPosition }}
        </p>
        <b-carousel
                id="carousel-1"
                :interval="0"
                controls
                indicators
                background="#ababab"
                img-width="1024"
                img-height="480"
                style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
                ref="slider"
                @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
                @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
        >

            <b-carousel-slide v-for="(item, index) in dataForProject" :id="index" >
                <img
                        slot="img"
                        class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
                        width="1024"
                        height="480"
                        :src="item.image_url"
                        alt="image slot"
                >
            </b-carousel-slide>
        </b-carousel>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import myDataBase from '../data2'

    export default {
        props:['actualPosition'],

        watch: {
            actualPosition: function () {

            },
        },


        data() {
            return {
                //slide: 0,
                dataForProject: myDataBase,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSlideStart(slide) {
                this.$emit('sendTheCarouselPosition', slide);
            },
            onSlideEnd(slide) {

            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my whole concept was wrong, and i was wrong about this.

I should have used the v-model for this whole thing. And nothing more.

I added the v-model to the target tags, and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I can get this done by two ways.

1 - **Global `EventBus`**
I will create an eventBus and register events on it from any file and listen it anywhere -

```
import { EventBus } from '@/eventBus' 
// simply import it to component which need listen the event


//Register Event where you have your methods - like In your COMP_B_TWO                   
 EventBus.$on('changeValue', () => { this.doSomething() })

// Emit event from another component
EventBus.$emit('changeValue')// Like directly from your COMP_A_TWO
```

To know how to create a eventBus follow this - [Global Event Bus Vue](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

---

2 - Use `state management` - `Vuex` Follow this link - [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Basically, it will have centralized store for all the components in an application. Whenever you wish to update state you will update to store. And all the other component using that state will react accordingly

Comment: Thank you, but i done with this part. The data is flowing corretly.

My problem in nutshell: i would like to call  the @sliding-start event from a function(), because i want the slider to go where the property shows.